# Logback unable to log in debug

Tags: java, logback, slf4j

I have a bit problem with a logback configuration, all of my --> log.debug("one log")
of my application aren't written is my debug.log file ... do you know why ?
bellow my logback configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<property name="LOG_PATH" value="/home/log/company"/>

<appender name="trafic" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_PATH}/trafic.log</file>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>

    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}]|%-5level|%thread|%logger.%method%cyan(\(%line\)): --- %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>50MB</totalSizeCap>
        <cleanHistoryOnStart>false</cleanHistoryOnStart>
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/trafic/year=%d{yyyy, aux}/month=%d{MM, aux}/day=%d{dd,
            aux}/trafic.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
        </fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>


<appender name="debug" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_PATH}/debug.log</file>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>DEBUG</level>
    </filter>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}]|%-5level|%thread|%logger.%method%cyan(\(%line\)): --- %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>50MB</totalSizeCap>
        <cleanHistoryOnStart>false</cleanHistoryOnStart>
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/debug/year=%d{yyyy, aux}/month=%d{MM, aux}/day=%d{dd,
            aux}/debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
        </fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>


<appender name="error" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_PATH}/error.log</file>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>ERROR</level>
    </filter>

    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}]|%-5level|%thread|%logger.%method%cyan(\(%line\)): --- %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>50MB</totalSizeCap>
        <cleanHistoryOnStart>false</cleanHistoryOnStart>
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/error/year=%d{yyyy, aux}/month=%d{MM, aux}/day=%d{dd,
            aux}/error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
        </fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<appender name="access" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_PATH}/access.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}]|%-5level|%thread|%logger.%method%cyan(\(%line\)): --- %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>50MB</totalSizeCap>
        <cleanHistoryOnStart>false</cleanHistoryOnStart>
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/access/year=%d{yyyy, aux}/month=%d{MM, aux}/day=%d{dd,
            aux}/access.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
        </fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<logger name="fr.company" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="error"/>
</logger>

<logger name="fr.company" level="WARN" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="error"/>
</logger>

<logger name="fr.company" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="debug"/>
</logger>

<logger name="fr.company" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="trafic"/>
</logger>

<logger name="org.apache.activemq" level="WARN" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="error"/>
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="access"/>
    <appender-ref ref="trafic"/>
</logger>

<logger name="springfox.documentation" level="WARN" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="error"/>
</logger>

<logger name="org.hibernate" level="WARN" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="error"/>
</logger>

<logger name="com.zaxxer" level="WARN" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="error"/>
</logger>

<root>
    <appender-ref ref="trafic"/>
    <appender-ref ref="access"/>
    <appender-ref ref="debug"/>
    <appender-ref ref="error"/>
</root>
```

And my dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
    </dependency>
```

And the logger declaration/utilization:

```
    @Slf4j
    @Service
    public class EventProcessor {

public EventProcessor() {
        log.info("Event initialized with '{}' uuid received", getEventUuid());
        log.debug("Event initialized with '{}' uuid received", getEventUuid());
                }
```

Do you know why, the INFO lines are correctly writted in debug.log and not DEBUG lines ? ...

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
<logger name="fr.company" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="error"/>
</logger>

<logger name="fr.company" level="WARN" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="error"/>
</logger>

<logger name="fr.company" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="debug"/>
</logger>

<logger name="fr.company" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="trafic"/>
</logger>
```

You are configuring the same logger four times.
Only the last configuration will be effective (which sets the log level to INFO).

What you seem to want is have the logger at DEBUG, add all appenders to it, and then filter again in the appenders to control the output (which you are already doing).

```
<logger name="fr.company" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="error"/>
    <appender-ref ref="debug"/>
    <appender-ref ref="trafic"/>
</logger>
```